# Change item displayed in view using jQuery and value selected in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, list, model-view-controller

In my view I have this dropdownlist:

```
Filter by: <select name="orderType" id="orderType">
                       <option value="All">All</option>
                       <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                       <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
                   </select>
```

Here's my model:

```
public class m_OrderInfo
{
    public int m_OrderID { get; set; }

    public string m_OrderName { get; set; }

    public string m_OrderType { get; set; }

    public DateTime m_OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

And when I display it, I create a List listObjsToDisplay that I pass to my view.

I want to change what is displayed based on the value selected in the dropdownlist. If the value is "Customer" I'd like to display only the orders which "m_OrderType" is "Customer" (it's a string). If the value is "Supplier", then only the "Supplier" will be displayed. Lastly, if it's all, display all the value.

But I don't want to get another list via server call, I just want to know if it's possible to change the list displayed in the view using jQuery.

**EDIT**

Well after some work and good advices I am progressing, but still need help.

Here's my view right now:

```
@using System.Globalization
@model List<MyApp.Models.OrderInfo>

<h2>
    Display Orders
</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Functional/Inventory.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Filter by: <select name="orderType" id="orderType">
                       <option value="All">All</option>
                       <option value="Customer Order">Customer Order</option>
                       <option value="Supplier Order">Supplier Order</option>
                   </select><br/>
    </p>
}

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Order ID<th>
            <th>Order Name</th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr class="@className order orderType-@Model[i].m_OrderType">
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderType)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderDate)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

And here's my jQuery script:

```
$('#orderType').change(function () {
    var showOrderType = $(this).val();
    if (showOrderType == "All") {
        alert("all is selected");
        $(".order").each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        alert("All are shown.");
    } else {
        alert("else condition struck");
        $(".order").each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        alert("all is hidden");
        $(".orderType-" + showOrderType).each(function () {
            alert("Code goes in here?");
            $(this).show();
        });
        alert("Code is done.");
    }
});
```

The script works partially as it successfully does the hide and show, but it never reaches the `alert("Code goes in here")` line, so I'm a bit clueless as to why it does not work.

Here's a sample of html code:

```
<h2>
    Display Suppliers Orders
</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Functional/magicAdmin.Inventory.js"></script>

<form action="/SupplierOrders/DisplaySuppliersOrders?Count=3&amp;PageCount=1&amp;TotalItemCount=3&amp;PageNumber=1&amp;PageSize=25&amp;HasPreviousPage=False&amp;HasNextPage=False&amp;IsFirstPage=True&amp;IsLastPage=True&amp;FirstItemOnPage=1&amp;LastItemOnPage=3" method="post">    <p>
        Filter by: <select name="orderType" id="orderType">
                       <option value="All">All</option>
                       <option value="Customer Order">Customer Order</option>
                       <option value="Supplier Order">Supplier Order</option>
                   </select><br/>
    </p>
</form>
    <table class="orderTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Order Name</th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
        </tr>
            <tr class="even order orderType-Supplier Order">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Box #1</td>
                <td>Supplier</td>
                <td>06-01-2012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd order orderType-Supplier Order">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Box #2</td>
                <td>Supplier Order</td>
                <td>06-01-2012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even order orderType-Supplier Order">
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Box #3</td>
                <td>Supplier Order</td>
                <td>01-01-0001</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you post your list of objects too..and you want to display only customer in the above select element or check if cutomer is clicked in the select

Comment: You mean you want to see my view, the model on which the list is based?

Comment: yes... cause its hard to understand what you actually want here...

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people tells me this. Sorry. I'll try to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your View.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr class="@className order orderType-@_item[i].m_OrderType">
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderID)</td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderName)</td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderType)</td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].m_OrderDate)</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Adding class `order` and `orderType-(whatever the Model says your OrderType is)` so jQuery can easily access it.

So in the jQuery

```
$('#orderType').change(function () {
    var showOrderType = $(this).val();

    if (showOrderType == "All") {
        //show all tr.order
        $(".order").each(function () {
            $(this).show()
        });
    } else {
        //hide all tr.order
        $(".order").each(function () {
            $(this).hide()
        });
        //show all tr.orderType-(Whatever the user selects)
        $(".orderType-" + showOrderType).each(function () {
            $(this).show()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try it and tell you the result.

Comment: I had to change the first line: `<tr class="@className order orderType-@Model[i].m_OrderType">`, I put `@Model` because the view was telling me an error using _item

Comment: Well it worked partially. If the `All` value is selected, all are displayed, but if "Customer" or "Supplier" value is selected none is displayed...

Comment: I have debugged it and the last line `//show all tr.orderType-(Whatever the user selects)`, the code does not go there

Comment: What is the HTML you are producing now? I'm sure the class is probably not as expected.

Comment: Ok, I will past an Html sample up above, but I think that the result's ok somehow.

Comment: `.m_OrderType-@Model[i].m_OrderType` <-- this isn't what my jQuery is looking for.. uses `.orderType-@Model[i].m_OrderType` instead or change the jQuery to look for `$(".m_OrderType-"+showOrderType)`

Comment: Or sorry, it was a try I made earlier ^^ I will correct it, but that won't change the problem.

Comment: If I debug the code using "Alert" for the `showOrderType` value, it is the good one.

Comment: The problem isn't the showOrderType..it's the `m_` you have in front.

Comment: But it is the value selected in the dropdownlist, and in the Html is it the value of the field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30159/discussion-between-michael-b-and-herve-s)

Answer (score 0):

Just a crude example

```
var customers = ['CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD'],
    suppliers = ['SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD']

$('#orderType').on('change', function() {
    var $subType = $('#subType'),
        orderType = this.value; 
    $subType.empty();
    var html = '';
    if(orderType === 'Customer') {
        for(var i =0; i< customers.length ; i++)
            html += '<option>' + customers[i] + '</option>'   ;     
    }
    else if(orderType === 'Supplier') {
         for(var i =0; i< suppliers.length ; i++)
            html += '<option>' + suppliers[i] + '</option>';      
    }
    else{
         for(var i =0; i< customers.length ; i++)
            html += '<option>' + customers[i] + '</option>';
         for(var i =0; i< suppliers.length ; i++)
            html += '<option>' + suppliers[i] + '</option>' ;     
    }
    $subType.append(html);
}).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/apsxX/)**